# iOS / Xcode: Group overlapping elements in Stack View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, button

For my game, I want to have this element for movement:

[image]

It's actually one image with 4 buttons on it:

[image]

**Now how do I go about making them adaptive as in a stack view?**

Since stack view doesn't really allow me to make elements overlap, I don't see an easy way here. Or I could make different stack views and make these overlap, but would that really be a good approach?

Is there another way to group elements in iOS, which allows more than horizontal and vertical stacking?

Comment: It is better if you use constraints rather than `UIStackView` here, but you wish to stack here, then take the 2 images in stack at a time and then align them in center of container view.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I'm really new to iOS programming and I thought the stack view was a "necessity" if you wanted your app to run well on different devices. I'll gladly only use constraints, it seems much easier. If you want to publish that as an answer, I'll accept it since it actually helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple suggests to use `UIStackView` rather than `NSLayoutConstraints` for designing the view but, it is not necessary to use `UIStackView` always.

According to mentioned situation in question, it is better if you use constraints rather than UIStackView here.

But you wish to stack here, then take the 2 images in stack at a time and then align them in center of container view.